# Test for difference in hazard in two consecutive time periods

Tags: survival, hazard, logrank-test

Let's say I have data on times-to-failure for a group of mechanical components in two consecutive years, Year 1 and Year 2. I would like to test the hypothesis that the hazard rate/survival behaviour is the same in Year 1 and Year 2. What's the best way to do this?

If I were comparing two independent groups, such as a treatment group and a control group from an RCT, I could just use a log-rank test. However, in this case, the groups are not independent - it's the same group in two consecutive time intervals. Would the log-rank test be inappropriate here? What other alternatives are there?

Comment: The groups may not be independent if the event process is not memoryless. However, the analysis set is intrinsic to the question: the event of failure (or success) in year 2 is predicated on success in year 1. Other assumptions: components only fail once, and tests are run in parallel (i.e. one component's failure doesn't affect another's risk).

Answer (score 2):

To calculate the logrank test, define two groups: A and B.  Group A will include all components and will either have an event in year one or will be censored at the end of the first year. Group B will include all components that survived at least one year. Then, restart the time origin to be the start of year 1 for those components in Group B (i.e. subtract 1 from the time to event or censoring).

It will be easier to test whether there is a difference in failure rates if you assume the times are exponential with possibly different rates in the two years; equivalently, the number of events is Poisson. You can use the likelihood ratio to test whether the rates are the same. If it is reasonable to assume that hazard rate is constant within each year (but the constant is possibly different in year 1 vs. year 2), I would do that.

Comment: Thank you, @John L. Just to clarify, for Group B, did you mean that I should restart the time origin to be the start of Year 2? That makes more intuitive sense to me, because the origin for all components is already the start of Year 1.

Also, I know that the inter-event times are not always exponential - in many cases they are better modeled as Weibull distributions with positive shape parameters. That's why I haven't been considering using methods based on the Poisson process. I suppose I could still try that as a simplified way to model the data.

Comment: Also, just wondering if you could point to any papers or books that mention using this approach? Thanks a lot!